# Lost bitcoins?? Help!

Tags: transactions

I transferred bitcoins from my Coinbase account to 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa and now I cannot find it nor do I know how to get it back. Where is my bitcoins??   [image]!

Comment: ask coinbase support

Comment: It [seems](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/1a73fce1f0de9191458296ee044fe6a4d9aebd2a8d2b1920950094087bc36ac9) to have gone through (at least, the amounts match up)

Answer (score 1):

> **I transferred bitcoins from my Coinbase account to 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa**

Well that is how you'd typically transfer some bitcoins to someone else's wallet to buy something. Its also how you'd move your bitcoins to a second wallet that you own (or to another address in the same wallet that you sent from)

You must know what the address is for - you must have had a reason for making the transfer.

> **I’m new to transferring of coins can you help me figure out how to receive it back**

Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed, undone or cancelled.

> **can you help me figure out ... how to send it somewhere?**

You already sent it somewhere.

> **I don’t understand! Confused newbie!**

That's OK, we all find it confusing to start with. It's perhaps a bit foolish to put much money into something you find confusing - but many other people do that. Perhaps the following will help make things a little clearer.

- Wallets don't contain bitcoins
- Wallets contain private keys that allows you to control the movement of some bitcoins in the blockchain.
- Private keys are not passwords or pass-phrases. Passwords are typically used to lock your wallet so that other people can't peek inside and see your private key. If your forget your password (it happens!) your wallet is useless. That doesn't matter if you follow the advice in the last point in this list.
- The blockchain is a ledger of all bitcoin movements. All full-nodes (typically desktop wallets, mining pools, "exchanges", etc) keep a copy. The blockchain is not owned by anyone (For example it is not the same as blockchain.info and is not owned or controlled by them).
- Your wallet has a private key. Some wallets can have several.
- From a private key, an address can be derived.
- You can send "bitcoins" from one address to another address.
- When I wrote "bitcoin" there I meant the unspent outputs of one or more previous transactions (UTXOs)
- When "bitcoins" are sent from one address to another, that is a transaction. The transaction details are added to (every copy of) the blockchain by miners (essentially).
- If the other address is not derived from a private key you own, you no longer have any control over those bitcoin.
- Your wallet should be able to show you all the private keys it knows of and all the addresses derived from those private keys and the total amount of "bitcoins" currently associated with those addresses.
- Sometimes it takes time for your wallet to "catch up" with the latest transactions. If your wallet is offline or has a problem, it might not show the latest values.
- If you don't write down the private keys (or a recovery phrase from which the private key can be created) and keep them somewhere safe, you, or your car-crash heirs, will eventually lose all your bitcoin forever (probably, OK possibly, it happens a lot). With only the private key (or recovery phrase) you (or a snoop) can re-create a wallet and gain control over the bitcoin associated with the addresses derived from the private key.

If you need more information to understand all this try

- [A gentle introduction to bitcoin](https://bitsonblocks.net/2015/09/01/a-gentle-introduction-to-bitcoin/)
- [Ever wonder how Bitcoin (and other cryptocurrencies) actually work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBC-nXj3Ng4)

If after reading that, you still have questions,

1. Use the search box above to find existing answers
2. Ask one question at a time here, be specific, try to make your question easy to read, take time to create a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that address [here](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/address/3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa). It looks like it received your0.01587661 BTC on 2018-07-11 at 15:54:55. You can see the transaction [here](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/1a73fce1f0de9191458296ee044fe6a4d9aebd2a8d2b1920950094087bc36ac9).

Anyone who knows the private key to that address can spend the coins there (currently 14.37955242 BTC). **Do not let anyone see the private key!**.

Comment: I’m new to transferring of coins can you help me figure out how to receive it back or how to send it somewhere. I don’t understand! Confused newbie!

Comment: You will need to explain where you got the address 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa from. For instance, do you have it printed on a sheet of paper (possible next to a QR code)? Or did you get it from a software-wallet on your computer or your 'phone. Or somewhere else?

According to [blockchain.info](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/address/3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa?offset=200&filter=6), that address received its first payment on 21st Novemver 2017 so do you remember setting up a wallet that day?

Comment: On 17th Dec 2017 at 01:38:47, someone **spent** 1.006169 BTC from that address. Whoever that was, they presumably have the private key. Can you remember if that was you, and if so, what you did?

Comment: I never transferred coins before July 11,  when I transferred it thst day it sent me to BRD and set up an account but it’s not there!

Comment: Your bitcoins are at 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa, so the question is *who owns 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa?*. If this address belongs to [brd.com](https://brd.com/), then they have your bitcoins, so you will have to ask them.

However, if they did *not* give you your private keys, you have *probably* signed up for a fake wallet. All reputable wallets give you *sole access* to your private keys.

Comment: The balance at 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa today is    15.9592355 BTC (worth $119124.89 at today's prices). If that's different from what you were expecting, then that address is probably not yours.

Comment: I do have a key for my BRD account , but not syncing anything

Comment: The address, 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa, is still receiving payments, most recently 0.00304656 BTC on 24th July at 12:49:20. Was that you? If that was not you, I think we can assume that 3FkenCiXpSLqD8L79intRNXUgjRoH9sjXa belongs to someone else. If it belongs to [brd.com](https://brd.com/support), you will have to ask them.

Comment: No it is not mine. I have talked to Coinbase and Blockchain is its no luck yet

Comment: You sent your bitcoins to someone else's address.Therefore, you have lost your bitcoins.  It seems likely that your BRD account is a scam, and not the real breadwallet.

For future reference, **ownership of bitcoins = ownership of private key**. (An exchange account is a *custodial* account — the exchange has custody of its customers' bitcoins because the exchange owns the private key.)